# Hotspot plugin scanWifi() is not working in Android ionic cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, wifi, hotspot

I'm facing an issue while scanning nearest wifi. I'm using ionic Cordova framework.
I have used a scanWifi method of Hotspot plugin to scan wifi list.
I have referred to the following link:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/hotspot/

My code is:

```
import { Hotspot, HotspotNetwork } from '@ionic-native/hotspot';

this.hotspot.scanWifi().then((networks: Array<HotspotNetwork>) => {
   this.availableWifiList = networks;
});
```

When app trying to scan the nearest wifi it returns an empty array of wifi list. But it's working on other Android devices.

The issue is reproduce in the following android device only for me.

Micromax:
Model Number: Micromax Q452 
Android Version: 7.0 
Android Security Patch Level: May 5, 2017

Also, it is working on other Android device having the same Android version.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably is an issue related to permissions. Remove/reinstall the app and grant permissions again. It should work.